# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson

Tags: java, selenium, gson, selenium-grid

In my eclipse project (dynamic web project) I have the following structure:

[image]

And I use the Gson library. This a servlet project for the selenium node. The node runs on a linux machine. When I hit the servlet I get an error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson...`

What am I missing? It works fine on windows.

Also here is an example command I use to start up a selenium node:

`java -cp "selenium-server-standalone.jar:selenium-extras.jar" org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 \
  -servlets com.node.servlets.ExecuteServlet \
  -role node \
  -hub http://$HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR:$HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT/grid/register \
  -maxSession 1 -browser $browserOpts`

selenium-extras.jar is the servlet project.

Comment: *And I use the Gson library.*... not visible though

Comment: I tried adding the library as well in the web-inf/lib folder. Same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the GSON jar file isn't on the classpath. Your classpath includes only two jar files: selenium-server-standalone.jar and selenium-extras.jar

> It works fine on windows

From the information in this post (at the time of this writing) it is not really possible to tell why it works on Windows because you haven't included the command you use to start up a selenium node on Windows

Comment: I added the jar in the classpath. Thanks!